# 2D canvas library for OpenLayers. Drawing custom interactive objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d, openlayers, konvajs

I am looking for the 2D canvas library like [Konva.js](https://konvajs.org) that I can use above OpenLayers 5.x.
I need to draw shapes with font inside that are interactive - can be dragged over the map to the appropriate location and rotated.
On the image below there is how it looks like with Konva.js over the image background.
Can you advise proper libs or techniques so the same can be implemented over the OpenLayers map?

[image: what I have now with Konva.js]

Comment: AFAIK OpenLayers is drawing a map image from the server and displaying it in a target DIV element. You can't host Konva in the same div but you could place another div on top of the OpenLayers div and target Konva there. This gives you the Konva drawing surface on top pf the OpenLayers surface and you can use all the Konva features etc. You will have to manage changes in scale or position (dragging) of the OpenLayers map and overcome the issue that the Konva layer captures mouse/touch gestures. Not simple but it may be a way forward.